# Validation rule syntax

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

I have an Account validation rule that fires when a specific picklist (Cooling Appliance) value is NOT selected on an Account that has a specific picklist (Program Name2) value selected on another picklist field.
Here is the formula:

```
ISPICKVAL(Program_Name2__c, "Smart House Call - CAC") && 
NOT (ISPICKVAL(Cooling_Appliance__c, "Central AC"))
```

I need to add additional logic so that the validation rule only fires when the Cooling Appliance picklist is not Null. Basically IF a user selects a value and it is NOT Central AC, the validation rule fires.
I tried adding the following to the beginning of the formula but I keep getting syntax errors stating ")" are missing but everytime I add one somewhere it doesnt help.

```
IF (NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Program_Name2__c)))) &&
```

I'm not sure if/where in the formula I should have the close parenthesis or if I actually need to add/change functions or operators.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IF at the start of your second function is unnecessary.

`NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Program_Name2__c))) && ISPICKVAL(Program_Name2__c, "Smart House Call - CAC") && NOT(ISPICKVAL(Cooling_Appliance__c, "Central AC"))`